# sqldeveloper exports integer inserts as strings

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

It seems like a bug in Version 19.4 which is fixed in 20+
I exported the content of my tables in sqldeveloper and the insert sql statements all have number as strings.
Example:

```
Insert into testtable(id,stuff) values ('1','Hello')
```

ID 1 becomes '1' in the export and I have trouble reading it in.
This is the case for every table. Is there a way to avoid the two ' ?

The DDL is:

```
create table TESTTABLE(
   ID INTEGER               not null
);
```

after executing its this in sqldeveloepr:

```
create table testtable{
"ID" Number(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
}
```

I noticed that I'm able to add such a line, if the constraints are not active. It seems like sqldeveloper convertes the string to a number internally.

Comment: Id must be a varchar2 or char and not a number in the table definition - show us your table DDL

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I added it

Comment: and I answered it @j-doe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table testtable(
"ID" Number(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
);

insert into testtable values (1);

commit;

select /*insert*/ * from testtable;
```

Running this, i get

```
Table TESTTABLE created.


1 row inserted.


Commit complete.

REM INSERTING into TESTTABLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TESTTABLE (ID) values (1);
```

No quotes on the number value/field. I did this with version 20.2 of SQL Developer.

Comment: And I got `Insert into TESTTABLE (ID) values ('1');` on 19.4, in **both** executing your script, as well as right-clicking the table, choosing "Export" as "insert statements". On this laptop I don't have 20.2 (and don't feel like downloading it now, I'm off to bed).

Comment: I don't believe you, I mean I do, but that's extremely weird, and I want proof... tomorrow :)

Comment: Well now seeings believings... must be a bug I plum forgot about. Version 20.4 will be available in a day or 5 if you wanna wait.

Comment: It's fine with me; ask the OP :)

Comment: Tested on 20.2, works **OK**. Must be a bug in 19.4

Comment: My workaround was to set the FK Constraints active after I inserted the numbers as strings, since sql developer seemed to convert them to number. Maybe we both should add a hint, that this is abug in an older version. Anyways, thank you for your help :)